# A proper way to read image from other thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I've got a class that runs a `Thread` with some data processing inside:

```
void thread_function()
{
  while (client != null)
  {
  ....some stuff...
  wrBitmap.WritePixels(rect, rgbch, rowLen, 0); // wrBitmap is WriteableBitmap
  OnFrameRdy(this, MyEventsArgs);
  }
}
```

How I can read `wrBitmap` from this `Thread` process without memory copying? I need to bind `wrBitmap` to my `Image` wpf control. Is that possible?

Or the only way of doing it - is to copy `wrBitmap` for some other variable in class and read it in my control? 
I dont want to copy variable, cause its going to give me a huge overhead in memory.

I thought I could use events and created my `OnFrameRdy` event, but is still doesnot let me use data.
It will be really cool if I could just type `Image.source = MyClass.wrBitmap`

Comment: what do you mean "does not let me use data"? what is your problem here? why can't you just do `Image.source = MyClass.wrBitmap` in the thread?

Comment: Are you intending to modify the WritePixels after assigning it to the Image control.

Comment: I'm getting `InvalidOperationException` exception when I'm trying to write `Image.source = MyClass.wrBitmap`. It's because wrBitmap is created in other `Thread`. And I dont know how to transmit wrBitmap data to my Image control without memory overhead.

Comment: Have you measured that the copying indeed causes a performance problem in your scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am *guessing* you are getting `InvalidOperationException` from attempt to set the `Source` property from different thread or using `Bitmap` in different thread than created (you **seriously** should be more explicit about what is the issue you are trying to solve).

If I am right, you should `Freeze` your bitmap (this disallows changes to it) and invoke assignment to `Image.Source` on the UI thread. This should work for you:

```
void thread_function()
{
    while (client != null)
    {
        ....some stuff...
        wrBitmap.WritePixels(rect, rgbch, rowLen, 0); // wrBitmap is WriteableBitmap
        wrBitmap.Freeze();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Image.Source = wrBitmap));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, the `InvalidOperationException` is my problem, because I'm trying to connect `Source` property and `Bitmap` from different threads. `Freeze` and `Dispatcher` works fine, but I want to use `wrBitmap` in cycle and `Freeze` do not let me do this. Is there any way to use same `wrBitmap` in cycle and provide it as `source` only when it's completed?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "use `wrBitmap` in cycle". Please elaborate on that, preferably as an edit to the question. If you want to incrementally build the image and show the result after each iteration , I don't believe it can be done without copying the intermediate image.